# React Native return one element to console log

Tags: ios, reactjs, console, react-native, console.log

If I set new Animated.Value(0) to a variable and then output that variable to the console log I get a never ending list like below. How can I return any single element to the log?

```
{ _children: [],
  x: 
   { _children: 
      [ { _children: 
           [ { _children: 
                [ { _props: 
                     { style: [Circular],
                       onStartShouldSetResponder: [Function],
                       onMoveShouldSetResponder: [Function],
                       onStartShouldSetResponderCapture: [Function],
                       onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: [Function],
                       onResponderGrant: [Function],
                       onResponderReject: [Function],
                       onResponderRelease: [Function],
                       onResponderStart: [Function],
                       onResponderMove: [Function],
                       onResponderEnd: [Function],
                       onResponderTerminate: [Function],
                       onResponderTerminationRequest: [Function],
                       children: 
                        { '$$typeof': {},
                          type: 
                           { [Function]
                             displayName: 'Text',
                             propTypes: [Object],
                             getDefaultProps: [Object],
                             childContextTypes: [Object],
                             contextTypes: [Object],
                             defaultProps: [Object] },
                          key: null,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Animated.Value` is a complex nested object with many properties. If you need to access the individual element you can use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access.

```
Ex:
let obj = new Animated.Value(0);
console.log(obj._value);//assuming _value is a valid property of the object
```

Comment: But how would you access for example the displayName here then? I tried dot notation but I've no idea how to refer to these components. Is it like obj._children._children._children._props or what? Whatever I tried doesn't seem to work.

Comment: stuff enclosed inside [ ] are arrays. Arrays are accessed by indices. I think it should be obj.x._children[0]._children[0]._children[0]._props.children.children.type.displayName.   I am not sure what exactly are trying to solve  ? Very  rarely do one needs to do something like this.

Comment: Well I'm probably going about it the wrong way. For example I set the value for an animation as follows: this.state.Anim.setValue(1); then what if I want to check if the value IS 1? Or just return the value basically.

Comment: I am not sure if I got the exact purpose of doing that. Do you want to set the value of the Animated.Value object again? If so you can do that using setValue method.  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html

Comment: Basically a getValue here is needed. Its been set to 1 so I for example want to ask If (animvalue==1) {then ....}.  I originally wanted to set it to 1 if it was 0 and 0 if it was 1 but didn't know how to get the value to check this.

Comment: It is basically async in nature. If you want to getValue you can use the addListener callback.  http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#content